# Copy constructor using "initWith" for "productFlavors" and "sourceSets"

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-type, android-sourcesets

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111442/1957401). Is it possible to create a copy constructor for `productFlavors` and `sourceSets` using `initWith` just like the one in the linked answer. That one worked great for `buildTypes`.

For `buildTypes` it was done this way:

```
debugfree.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
```

Is this possible for `productFlavors` and `sourceSets` as well?

Comment: awesome question, this is what I've been looking for. Looks like `productFlavors` have this trick to *combine* the flavor instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341852/3763032

Comment: Looks like it has been added in 2021, but somehow I can't make it work. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165642956